# How can I get value of PlatformColor in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I need to provide a color to a custom theme in my app in the rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) form, I would like to use a system color and therefore, I am using the PlatformColor API.

`{ onSurface: PlatformColor("@android:color/system_neutral1_900") }`

It returns an object rather than a string. Is there any way to extract an rgba representation of this color returned by the API?